# find: missing argument to `-exec' in Linux

Tags: linux, cron

I am getting the **find: missing argument to `-exec'** while trying to put the following code in crontab,

```
*/01 * * * * find /<folder1/folder2/etc>/* -user "<username>" -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Not sure where I am missing. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
JDG

Comment: 1. is it your style or you have path like this `/<folder1/folder2/etc>/*` . 2. cron likes full path to binaries `/usr/bin/find`

Comment: Thank YOU for the reply Helleseher.                                                                             
1. This is the full path of the location from where I want to delete files. For example, 'Delete everything within 'etc' folder, which is 'within 'folder2', which is within 'folder1'.    2. I will try with the full path of the binary 'find'.